# Storing Multiple Datasets from R Shiny Reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm working in R Shiny, and I'd like for the user to be able to upload multiple data sets (as many as he or she wants) and have the data accessible in another tab. I can't seem to figure it out. I have a solution, but it's sloppy and it involves global variables and it re-uploads the data when the user switches tabs instead of accessing it. I'd like to be able to do this using reactives. Here is what I have so far

```
library("shiny")

server <- function(input, output) {

  in_data <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$file1, "Select a file!")
    )

    read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
  })

output$file_info <- renderTable({
data.frame(in_data())
})

}

ui <- navbarPage('Navigation Bar',
  tabPanel('File Information', verbatimTextOutput('fileInfo'),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File', accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma = ',', Semicolon = ';', Tab = '\t'), ','),
    radioButtons('quote', 'Quote', c(None = '', 'Double Quote'='"', 'Single Quote' = "'"),'"'),
    tags$hr()
    ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("file_info")
    )
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd like for the user to be able to upload multiple "file1"'s and have R store them off for easy access later. Any ideas? Much appreciated

Comment: Could you just have a list that stores each of the datasets as an element in the list?

Comment: ...and store that list within `reactiveValues()`,...

Comment: For some reason, I can't make it work in Shiny. There isn't an append function that I know about, and when I try to do something like: `mylist[length(list) + 1] <<- new_df`. Is there another way to to it?

Comment: Again any help is much appreciated